# Mysql ignorar acentos

Tags: php, mysql

Estou num projeto com bootstrap e php + mysql. Nele tenho uma busca simples:

```
$y = mysql_query("SELECT *,date_format(`ultimologin`,'%d/%m às %H:%i') as `ulogin` FROM $tabela WHERE estado='$estado' COLLATE utf8_general_ci ORDER BY ultimologin DESC LIMIT $limite") or die(mysql_error());
```

Esse "COLLATE" eu adicionei recentemente numa tentativa de resolver o seguinte  problema:

Quando, por exemplo,

```
$estado='São Paulo';
```

ele lista normalmente. Mas quando

```
$estado='Sao Paulo';
```

nada é retornado.

Quero que obtenha o resultado tanto com quanto sem o acento.

Obs. 1: Em alguns casos passo a variavel via URL ($_GET) e em outros não. Assim, por garantia, montei uma função básica que retira os acentos... e preciso que seja assim.

Obs. 2: A tabela e os campos estão em utf8_general_ci bem como a página (que é utf-8).

Curiosidade: Olhando lá no PhpMyAdmin vejo assim "SÃ£o Paulo".

Por fim, digo que já procurei muito antes de decidir perguntar aqui.

Conto com sua ajuda.

Comment: Vai precisar mudar o collation. Configure o PHP pra usar utf8 tbm

Answer (score 3):

Resolvemos o problema definido as tabelas como `utf8_unicode_ci`

Convertemos o tipo de entrada de caracteres da tabela

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Depois convertemos os dados que já existe para a mesma codificação utilizada na Query acima.

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela`
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

ou ainda em carater "gambiarra" vc faz a query usando o collate

```
Select * from TABELA where CAMPO like '%texto_para_encontrar%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

obs: latin1_swedish_ci tbm serve

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Mas não consegui resolver dessa forma... O meu banco de dados continua "SÃ£o Paulo" etc... Fiz uma gambiarra pra tocar o projeto, até conseguir converter o BD ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 1):

Uma pequena contribuição. Se for optar pela consulta direta, coloque o collate atual do campo antes do valor buscado, desta forma (em negrito):

Select * from TABELA where CAMPO like **_utf8** '%texto_para_encontrar%' collate utf8_general_ci

Caso contrário pode gerar um erro como este: COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).